# natural join or outer join in this application?

Tags: sql

I have three tables that i need them joined in a single output table but no join or comma seem to produce the desired output

the table are

```
                        E  G  | E  S  | E  B
```

the data looks like this

```
                        e1 g1 |  e1 s1 | e1 b1
                        e2 g2 |  e2 s2 | e2 b2



select e1,g,s,b from
(select e as e1, m as g from table x where m=g),
(select e as e2, m as s from table x where m=s),
(select e as e3, m as b from table x where m=b)
where e1=e2 AND e2=e3;
```

the out put that i want is

```
                   E | G | S | B

                   e1| g1| s1| b1

                   e2| g2| s2| b2
```

but i get the multiplication result

```
                       e1 g1 s1 b1
                       e1 g1 s1 b2
                       e1 g1 s2 b1
                       e1 g1 s2 b2
```

i tried to use natural join instead of the comma, but i don't get the desired output, i don't understand the problem a natural join should easily solve the problem right?

Comment: Unclear what `the table are` is actually referring to.  It can't be a single table, because the column names repeat.  So...what is it?

Comment: your tables are very much unpredictable!!!

Comment: sorry the tables are

Comment: i'm sorry for uncarity, i have a single table with the column M, that has values G,S,B or N i want to select the values E corresponding to G the values corresponding to S and B each one in a column

Comment: As a rule of thumb try to avoid natural joins. They are obscure and bug prone. Worst of all they don't survive well after some time when the database [inexorably] changes.

Comment: I'm totally lost.  Your subqueries seem to suggest that you have only one table.  But your data and text suggest multiple tables.

Answer (score 1):

use **correlated query** :

```
select e.col1 E,e.col2 G,(select s.col2 from s where s.col1=e.col1 ) S, 
(select 
b.col2 from b where b.col1=e.col1 ) B
from e;
```

check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82244c/1

Answer (score 1):

A simple `JOIN` would do:

```
select
  e.e,
  e.g,
  s.s,
  b.b
from e
join s on s.e = e.e
join b on b.e = e.e
```

Result (see [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ff1d3/1) ):

```
e   g   s   b
--  --  --  --
e1  g1  s1  b1
e2  g2  s2  b2
```

For reference, here's the data I used:

```
create table e (e varchar(2), g varchar(2));
insert into e (e, g) values ('e1', 'g1'), ('e2', 'g2');

create table s (e varchar(2), s varchar(2));
insert into s (e, s) values ('e1', 's1'), ('e2', 's2');

create table b (e varchar(2), b varchar(2));
insert into b (e, b) values ('e1', 'b1'), ('e2', 'b2');
```

**A final note**: As a rule of thumb try to avoid natural joins. They are obscure and bug prone. Worst of all they don't survive well after some time when the database [inexorably] changes.

Comment: "They are obscure and bug prone" -- do you have citations for those claims?

Comment: @onedaywhen: because they rely on column _names_ rather than declared foreign keys - and which columns it picks isn't that obvious. Can you tell me which join columns are used in [this example](https://rextester.com/WMGR3194)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: straw man: you created a schema with duplicate data element names. How about using the NHS data dictionary as a better example? (https://www.datadictionary.nhs.uk/data_dictionary/data_field_notes/data_field_notes_Cou_child.asp)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: That is how natural join functions _by design_. They may not be to your taste but I was asking about obscurity and bugginess. P.S. no join type (nor any other SQL relational operator) depends on declared foreign keys, you are confusing SQL DDL and SQL DML.

Comment: @onedaywhen: I know that no join type uses declared foreign keys and I know that's how the SQL standard defined this join type. From my point of view the only way the natural join _would_ make sense if it did use FK constraints. Using a natural join in production code is simply begging for trouble. The names in my (made up) example aren't that far fetched though. Using `id` as the PK column name might be questionable. But column names like `created_at` (or `name` or `due_date`) might indeed exist in more than one table and then you **are** in trouble if you use a natural join

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I find `name` equally questionable. It has nothing to do with standard SQL and everything to do with language design. Your `created_at` data elements are mixing data and metadata (I'd use a different schema for such auditing). I get that you don't like `natural join` but this doesn't equate to 'bugs'.

Answer (score -2):

A simple `NATURAL JOIN` works well:

```
SELECT e, g, s, b
  FROM e NATURAL JOIN s NATURAL JOIN b;
```

Result ( see [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5ff1d/2/0) ):

```
e   g   s   b
--  --  --  --
e1  g1  s1  b1
e2  g2  s2  b2
```

**A final note**: Natural join is only join type you need and has advantages over 'legacy' joins e.g. no duplicate columns means you don't require range variables to resolve them.

Does your SQL product of choice contain bugs? All software does; if it concerns you, try a different SQL product.

If you are concerned that uncontrolled changes to the schema will affect the semantics of your query in the future then there are various ways of coding defensively e.g. using CTEs:

```
WITH e1 AS ( SELECT e, g FROM e ),
     s1 AS ( SELECT e, s FROM s ),
     b1 AS ( SELECT e, b FROM b )
SELECT e, g, s, b
  FROM e1 NATURAL JOIN s1 NATURAL JOIN b1;
```

Comment: `natural join` is most definitely **not** the "only join type you need" - as matter of fact you should avoid `natural join` like the plague.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: on the contrary, since switching exclusively to `natural join` I've never needed another join type.